# Creating MySQL Unique constraint through multiple table

Tags: mysql, sql, unique, relation

I would like to make a unique constraint that uses a value that is found within a relationship.

## Table Structure:

```sql
table1
    - id PRIMARY KEY
    - column1
    - column2
    - table2_id
table2
    - id PRIMARY KEY
    - column1
    - column2
    - table3_id
table3
    - id PRIMARY KEY
    - column1
    - column2
```

## Expected Result

A unique constraint on table1 where it only accept a unique value combination of `table1`.`column1`, `table1`.`column2`, and `table3`.`column2` values

### What I imagine the SQL query to look like:

*which of course, is not working*

```sql
ALTER TABLE `table1` 
    ADD UNIQUE `table1_unique_idx` 
    INNER JOIN `table2` ON `table1`.`table2_id` = `table2`.`id` 
    INNER JOIN `table3` ON `table2`.`table3_id` = `table3`.`id` 
    (`table1`.`column1`, `table1`.`column2`, `table3`.`column2`);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: 'Is this possible?' no it isn't indexes can only refer to columns in the table for which ithey are being defined. Also foreign keys can only reference 1 table so don't appear to be an option. Try adding sample data as text to help clarify your requriement.

Comment: Have you considered a trigger instead?

Comment: @P.Salmon I have. I just thought if I post this question here someone might throw what I thought of, but I think at this point it's not a possibility.

Comment: Any constraint can check the condition within current row only. It cannot refer to another row or another table. So the task cannot be solved using a constraint. The trigger is the only option.